# Handle back pressed on fragment then continue navigating

Tags: android, kotlin

I am listening back button pressed on my fragment as follows

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    podcastViewModel.removePodcast();
    // THEN - continue navigating 
}
```

How can I perform a task like `removePodcast();` then after continue navigation to back. The above code intercept back button pressed but doesn't continue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding the usual back-pressed behaviour, which is why it doesn't navigate back. You need to call `parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()` (or `findNavController().popBackStack()` if you're using the Navigation component).

Your other option is to do `setEnabled = false` in the callback after you remove your podcast (meaning the handler won't be called next time) and then immediately fire a back-pressed event with `activity?.onBackPressed()`. That will handle it with the default behaviour (unless you've added more dispatchers! In which case it'll fall through to the next one)

---

**edit:** I've used the `popBackStack` stuff myself, but it *might* be a better idea to use the "disable dispatcher and re-fire" approach in general. Purely because the standard behaviour could possibly change (a lot is going on with back stacks and navigation development) so hardcoding a `popBackStack` call might lead to problems down the line.

I don't know what the official line is though - [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) have this to say:

> **Changing the enabled state on the `OnBackPressedCallback` is strongly recommended** for temporary changes as it maintains the ordering described above, which is particularly important if you have callbacks registered on multiple different nested lifecycle owners.

but that's more about changing the response to a back press temporarily, not handling one press and messing around, firing multiple events to generate a particular standard behaviour

Comment: When disabling the dispatcher, the deprecated method "activity?.onBackPressed()" is needed to continue the nav stack flow in the back direction. Is there a way to replace it?
@cactustictacs

Comment: @Orwakassab It's only deprecated in the base `Activity` class since *API 33*: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed() and like it says there, they're using a different back-navigation model in the latest Android version. `OnBackPressedDispatcher` is part of the *AndroidX* `activity` support library, and if you're using that (i.e. you're using `AppCompatActivity`) then it's not deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#onBackPressed()

Answer (score 2):

Just found a way! The callback should be disabled or removed

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    podcastViewModel.removePodcast();
    this.remove()
    activity?.onBackPressed()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one!

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    val callback: OnBackPressedCallback = object :
        OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            podcastViewModel.removePodcast();
            this.remove()
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun getOnBackInvokedDispatcher(): OnBackInvokedDispatcher {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback {
        if (enableBackPress) {
            //Do your operation here
        } else {
            toast("Please wait...")
        }
    }
    return super.getOnBackInvokedDispatcher()
}
```